# Put Live background like in weather apps on Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

i Want to put live background on Activity just like weather apps which changes with Rainfall, sunshine, clouds depending on weather conditions
[image]

Comment: So, what you have done to do that?

Comment: Just set the background image according to the weather condition

Comment: no i want a live moving background like other weather apps dp, and i have implemented a GIF in the background but it doesnt fit all the mobile screens

Answer (score 0):

Animating a graphic itself is a memory consuming operation and can make the phone run out of memory fast. GIF is not recommended on android, since it takes to much memory on the system, and not natively supported by Android phone, but you can load GIF animation with some tricks, like using network image loader library like Glide, or use webview, etc.

Another way is using animation list.

Another way is make a custom view that you can handle the draw by yourself. The idea is you animate the draw by calling invalidate at certain delay after change the image on onDraw method of View.

If you want to make it better for performance and memory, you can use OpenGL directly

Comment: Many apps out there even video players are using live backgrounds on their activities, Just like weather apps where its raining etc is shown on the background